# How to do tagged logging in Express

Tags: node.js, express

A log for a request looks like this:

```
Received a new product Widget-1
Started to store product
POST /products 200 52.240 ms - 2
Product stored
```

Where the first, second and fourth lines are logs I created using console.log. The third is done by Morgan.

My problem is that the (asynchronous) function that stores the products in the db is relatively slow so I have logs like this

```
Received a new product Widget-1
Started to store product
POST /products 200 52.240 ms - 2
Received a new product Widget-2
Started to store product
POST /products 200 52.240 ms - 2
Product stored
Product stored
```

How can I tag each log line so I can group the logs of a request easily? Something like

```
[11111] Received a new product Widget-1
[11111] Started to store product
[11111] POST /products 200 52.240 ms - 2
[aaaaa] Received a new product Widget-2
[aaaaa] Started to store product
[aaaaa] POST /products 200 52.240 ms - 2
[11111] Product stored
[aaaaa] Product stored
```

The tag can any format, I just want to filter the lines that belong to the same request.

I tried this in Express creating a middleware that assigned a random number to a req.id and used that number in each console.log, for example:

```
console.log(`[${req.id}] Started to store product`)
```

But I would prefer to define the tag in a middleware or configuration, and then use `console.log("Started to store product")`

Comment: It looks like you want to initialize a sort of transaction and then log everything that is related to this transaction in a specific way (with an ID here). I think you have no choice to what you just did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attaching an unique ID to the req was the right direction.
Pushing it further, we can attach a `log()` function to the req that will log anything prefixed with the `req.id`.

Which gives us:

```
const myMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  req.id = getUniqueId();
  req.log = (...args) => console.log(`[${req.id}]`, ...args);
};
```

... and later use:

```
// later
req.log('Started to store product'); // Outputs `[123456] Started to store product`
```

---

Regarding the fact that you want the Morgan log to be tagged also, this will not be possible to tag it on a per-request basis unless Morgan can be provided a custom log function.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a library specifically to enable this called [**scribbles**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scribbles)

When you use the **scribbles** [middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scribbles#example-using-express--axios-within-aws). Everywhere in your App you call scribbles logger will automatically tag the output based on the parent request.

- Based on your requirements I changed the outputted format string.

The `spanId` contains **a shortened** 1) the current commits hash 2) the parent ID 3) the process ID and 4) the number of requests. This means you can separate requests(via some regex in your log collector) just based on this `spanId` while also getting some useful basic information

```
const scribbles = require('scribbles');
const express   = require('express');

scribbles.config({
   format:'{time} [{spanId}] <{logLevel}> {fileName}:{lineNumber} {message}'
})

const app = express();

// start a trace for each incoming request.
app.use(scribbles.middleware.express);

app.get('/', function (req, res){

  scribbles.log("incoming");
  // 2022-06-27T16:24:06.473 [090e8e40000005] <log> index.js:17 incoming

  // ... do some work

}) // END app.get '/'


app.listen(port, () => scribbles.status(`App is ready!`))
```

**scribbles** can do a **lot more** in helping your log events. [Check out some of the examples in the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scribbles) to see about performance monitoring and distributed tracing across microservices